# Change app wide font-size using a theme for Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to make every bit of text larger on an Android application, mimicking what happens when you change the default font size in the global settings screen? I want for the user to select a font size in the settings screen and all of the text to change, without needing to put extra style tags onto my individual screens.

I have three themes so far which correctly change the font size for `TextView`'s but not things like `EditText`, or `ListView` elements

```
<style name="AppThemeSmall" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Small</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Small</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeMedium" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeLarge" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Large</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Large</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 7):

I ended up adding styles to the xml, it felt cleaner that way and I had more control.

each layout xml (inc. EditText, AutoCompleteTextView)

```
 <TextView
   style="?textTitle"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/ref" />
```

attrs.xml

```
<attr name="textTitle" format="reference" />
```

styles.xml (note that I've overridden the spinner style as well to keep the sizes consistent

```
<style name="AppTheme.Small">
    <item name="textTitle">@style/small_title_text</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/spinner_small</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Medium">
    <item name="textTitle">@style/medium_title_text</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/spinner_medium</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Large">
    <item name="textTitle">@style/large_title_text</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/spinner_large</item>
</style>


<!-- SMALL FONT SIZE -->
<style name="small_title_text">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>


<!-- MEDIUM FONT SIZE -->
<style name="medium_title_text">
    <item name="android:textSize">19sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="medium_list_text"></style>

<!-- LARGE FONT SIZE -->
<style name="large_title_text">
    <item name="android:textSize">23sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="large_list_text"></style>

<!-- SPINNER STYLES -->
<style name="spinner_small">
    <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">0dip</item>
</style>

<style name="spinner_medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">21sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">0dip</item>
</style>

<style name="spinner_large">
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">0dip</item>
</style>
```

Then I set the theme before every activity is created.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PreferenceHelper mPrefs = PreferenceHelper.getInstance(this);
    setTheme(mPrefs.getTheme());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom widget which extends from a basic widget. During initialisation retrieve the font-setting from the shared preferences. I guess you will store it there, when settings are changed. During initialisation the textsize of the widget is set to the stored setting. In code:

```
public class MyCustomTextView extends TextView {

    public MyCustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }   

    public MyCustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        float size = .... // retrieve from your shared preferences
        setTextSize(size);
    }
}
```

This way you can extend all widgets which have a textsize attribute and change it during initialisation.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't do exactly this in the end but I have stored the theme in the preferences as you suggested.