# How to use the same textSize value for multiple components in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, text-size

I need to use the following attribute in several **TextViews**, where can I store it so that when the value changes they are all changed?

```
 android:textSize="12sp"
```

I have the resource files **themes.xml** and **strings.xml**, I want to do the same but for the text size

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950010/change-app-wide-font-size-using-a-theme-for-android

Comment: I think not, I just want to have a variable stored in some xml, that when changing it all the textSizes change, but I don't know what is the correct way to create it

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128178/how-to-use-dimens-xml-in-android

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the help of themes.
In your values res folder create some file, for instance, size.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="my_text_size" type="dimen">12sp</item>
</resources>
```

Then, in your values/styles.xml create new theme:

```
<style name="MyTextView" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/my_text_size</item>
</style>
```

Then, apply your new style to your TextView widgets:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/MyTextView"
            android:text="HELLO1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/MyTextView"
            android:text="HELLO2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```